# Make a simple nlp model on python/spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I would like to point out that I am new to Spacy. I would like to train a model with my own labels and then show him texts that he has not seen and that he "predise" me future labels on texts that I have not yet read.

Here is the somewhat rudimentary code:

```
nlp = spacy.blank('en')


ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')



labels = ['PERSON', 'LOC']
for label in labels:
    ner.add_label(label)


TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is John ? He is far !", {"entities": [(7, 11, "BOY")]}),
    ("I like Lara. She likes you too !", {"entities": [(7, 11, "GIRL")]}),
]
examples = []
for text, annots in TRAIN_DATA:
    examples.append(Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annots))
nlp.begin_training()
for i in range(20):
    random.shuffle(examples)
    for batch in minibatch(examples, size=8):
        nlp.update(batch)
text = "Where is London ? I don't Sara"
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

No matter how many different codes I try I can’t make him predict anything, it doesn’t literally get me anything. Ideally I’d like him to put: Laura Girl

I also tried with pre-trained templates `en_core_web_sm` but it only predicts me pre-trained labels and not mine, I don’t understand too much.

Comment: labels = ['GIRL', 'BOY'] Of course I have put the right label, it is a mistake of inatention on my part, but my problem remains the same.